# rc-s380 unable to read from my Android smartphone

Tags: android, python, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am working on a project where NFCpy is installed on Raspberry PI 3 and Sony card reader rc-s380 is connected to it.

I have written a python test application to read and write data to tags. 
I am able to detect, read and write to Type2 tags (passive tags)
But I am unable to read from my Android smartphone (NFC enabled). It is able to engage(Type 4 tag) and get tag information but unable to read tag. Why is this ?

Here is my python source:

```
clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')
if clf :
 while clf.connect(rdwr={
'on-startup': startup,
'on-release': release,
}):
```

Comment: Do you have an application running on the Android device that emulates a Type 4 tag?

Comment: Yes. I m using NFC reTag application

Comment: Can't Sony rc-s380 communicate with active device ? For example my smartphone.. ?   Passive tags are working fine.

Comment: The NFC ReTag app is a card reader application. You must use a card emulator app to if you run RC-S380 as a card reader.

Comment: nfcpy can operate in peer-to-peer mode (probably that's what you are refering to as "active device"). However, you explicitly configured it to operate in reader/writer mode. Hence you need a counter part that is (or emulates) a tag.

Comment: Thanks .. is there any card emulator app available on Android market ?? Or a new one should be developed ?